# How to accept Querystring from URL into Angular route?

Tags: angular

I need to accept this format of URL into my Angular app:

```
http://localhost:4200/approve/VA/28/20/0=2022-02-02&1=2022-02-03&2=2022-02-04
```

My route path is this

```
path: 'approve/:vacation/:id/:vacationsLeft/:dates'
```

Unfortunately when I visit the URL I get :

```
http://localhost:4200/approve/VA/28/20/0
```

I am getting the URL from an email and I can't change the format of the query. Is there a way to pass it into Angular route?

Comment: You'll need to encode those URL parameters into a URL-safe format, because they include reserved characters (like `=`, `&`), which are not permitted in arbitrary places.

You can read more about it here: https://developers.google.com/maps/url-encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow-up on my comment, you can encode the `dates` URL parameters with something like this:

```js
let vacactionCode = 'VA';
let vacationId = 28;
let vacationsLeft = 20;
let dates = encodeURIComponent("0=2022-02-02&1=2022-02-03&2=2022-02-04");

let url = `http://localhost:4200/approve/${vacactionCode}/${vacationId}/${vacationsLeft}?dates=${dates}`;
```

Then you would need to update your route, because `:dates` is no longer part of the path, it is now an optional parameter:

`path: 'approve/:vacation/:id/:vacationsLeft`